# Set the maximum chr length of a TextBlock in XAML

Tags: xaml

How would I set the number of characters a user is allowed to input in a TextBlock in xaml?

Would I do it on the Model or create some sort of custom attribute to handle it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you limit the length of Text visible in a WPF TextBlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170817/can-you-limit-the-length-of-text-visible-in-a-wpf-textblock)

Answer (score 14):

TextBlock doesn't have a MaxLength, neither does Label. TextBox does. Users cannot input into a TextBlock unless you have modified it.

Is it really a TextBlock you want to limit or did you mean a TextBox? If it is a TextBox you can simply use the MaxLength property.

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" MaxLength="5" />
```

If it really is a TextBlock you are using and somehow allowing a user to input data into it, then switch to use a TextBox. If it is the TextBlock style you are after, you can style the TextBox to look like a TextBlock.

Comment: MaxLength is not working. user can type more characters than 5.

Comment: Are you sure you have a styled TextBox and not a TextBlock?

Answer (score 11):

Without creating a custom control, you have a few options.

You could try to size the `TextBlock` to fit your expected text exactly, but that gets ugly fast trying to account for varying input or different font sizes.

Instead, you can verify the character length of the string to be assigned to the `TextBlock.Text` property and limit it if necessary.

```
string s = "new text";
if (s.Length > maxLen)
    textBlock1.Text = s.Substring(0, maxLen);
else
    textBlock1.Text = s;
```

Another option is to use the `TextWrapping` and `TextTrimming` properties.  The following attributes could be added to your `TextBlock` xaml to add line wrapping and "..." to denote that text exists beyond the size of the `TextBlock`.

```
<TextBlock ... TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use 'TextTrimming' Property of a Textblock. Set TextTrimming = "CharacterEllipsis". You might need to play with **Width** to manage how many characters you really want to display.

```
<TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding Subject}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either Set MaxHeight = "SomeHeight" and trim the overflow with

```
<TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding LongText}"
```

Or Use TextBox like **Textblock** by setting

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
 MaxLength="100"
```

Answer (score 0):

An additional approach would be to format the string that you show, using StringFormat.

For example, I wanted to display a `decimal x`, but only up to 5 digits after the decimal point:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding x, StringFormat={}{0:F5}}"/>
```

See [Use StringFormat to add a string to a WPF XAML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278515/use-stringformat-to-add-a-string-to-a-wpf-xaml-binding) for additional examples.